# Unexpected z-order of <div> and its ::before

Tags: html, css, z-index, pseudo-element

I have two overlapping dots from a `div` and its `::before` and want the left/main dot to appear **ON TOP** of the right/pseudo dot.

```css
div, div::before {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
div {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  left: -11px;
  transform: translateX(5px);
}
div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: -2px;
  left: 9px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Due to both being positioned relative or absolute, I would have expected the different z-index values to cause the left/main dot to appear **ON TOP** of the right/pseudo dot (which is what I want).

(There is a reason I need the main dot to be on the left, so I'd rather not switch main/pseudo.)

Comment: The `transform` property changes what the containing block is, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block#identifying_the_containing_block

Comment: But even without the transform, the result is the same: https://jsbin.com/luvucahoso

Comment: Will help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateZ

Comment: _"But even without the transform, the result is the same"_ - yes, the `z-index` on the div would also need to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `transform-style: preserve-3d` on the div and `transform: translateZ(-1px)`on the before?

```css
div, div::before {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
div {
  position: relative;
  left: -11px;
  transform: translateX(5px);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: 9px;
  background-color: blue;
  transform: translateZ(-1px);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Why such an extensive response for such a straightforward solution?